# Casting a double to another numeric type

Tags: java, casting, primitive-types

there is something puzzling me and I did not find much information on the VM specs. It's a bit obscure and that'd be nice if someone could explain me.

These few lines of code.....

```
double myTest = Double.MAX_VALUE;

System.out.println("1. float: " + (float)myTest);
System.out.println("2. int: " + (int)myTest);
System.out.println("3. short: " + (short)myTest);
System.out.println("4. byte: " + (byte)myTest);
```

..... produce this output:

1. float: Infinity
2. int: 2147483647
3. short: -1
4. byte: -1

`byte`, `short` and `int` are 8, 16, 32 bit with two's complement. `float` and `double` are 32 and 64 bit IEEE 754 ([see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)).

From my understanding, the max value of a `double` implies that all the bits of the mantisse (52 bits) are switched to 1. Therefore it's not (very) surprising that a cast to short or to byte returns -1 i.e all bits are switched to 1. It seems that the cast keeps the 'tail' of the `double` so that it fits into 8 bit `byte` or 16 bit `short`.

What surprises me is the cast to `int` and, to a lesser extent, the cast to `float`.
How is it possible to get "2. int: 2147483647" which is 0x7FFFFFFF, the maximal value while short and byte 3. and 4. are -1 ?

The cast to `float` is also weird. If the 32 bits at the 'tail' of `myTest` were kept, then shouldn't it generate a `NaN` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JLS spells out the rules in section [5.1.3 Narrowing Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3). The rules depend on the target type.

**`float`:**

> A narrowing primitive conversion from double to float is governed by the IEEE 754 rounding rules (§4.2.4). This conversion can lose precision, but also lose range, resulting in a float zero from a nonzero double and a float infinity from a finite double. A double NaN is converted to a float NaN and a double infinity is converted to the same-signed float infinity.

**`int` and `long`:**

> one of the following two cases must be true:
>
> - ...
> - The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type int or long.

**`byte`, `char` and `short`:**

If the target type is `byte`, `char` or `short`, the conversion it two-step. First, the `double` is converted to `long` as explained above. Then, the `long` is converted to the final type as follows:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

Comment: Thanks this is very interesting. So once the double is casted to an int ("with the largest representable value" in my example), it is casted to a byte or a short with a different philosophy ("discards all but the n lowest order bits").

Comment: @Jerome: Pretty much (except that I think that the intermediate type is `long`, but doesn't affect the result).

Comment: It's worth noting that although casting `double` to `float` may cause some distinct values to become indistinguishable, that's a minor issue compared to the fact that casting `float` to `double` may cause things that should be considered indistinguishable to instead be sorted *wrongly*.  For example, given `float f=16777217; double d=16777216.0000001;`, which is larger--`f` or `d`?  How about `float ff=1E38f*10f; double dd=1e300;`?  Regarding `ff` and `dd` as "indistinguishable" wouldn't be great, but saying `ff>dd` is hundreds-of-orders-of-magnitude wrong.